# What does "wheelchair dependence" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've read a sentence:

> For 17 of them, the disease had progressed to the point of "wheelchair dependence" for mobility.

What does "wheelchair dependence for mobility" mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"**Wheelchair dependence  for mobility**" means **to depend on wheelchair for movement**.

The sentence means:

> That particular disease has spread in those 17 people so much that
>   they cannot move on their own.They now have to depend on wheelchair
>   for their movement.